# reboot script to start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, reboot

My rails server is running under a deployer user and I normally start it like this

```
#restart.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u deployer -H bash -l
cd /var/www/html/cms/
./server -e staging start
```

So when I login over SSH i run ./restart.sh and that works great.

I'm trying to do this automatically after a reboot so I've added a reboot_site.service in
/etc/systemd/system/reboot_site.service

```
# /etc/systemd/system/reboot_site.service

[Unit]
Description=reboot_site
After=syslog.target network.target


[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/cms
# If you use rbenv:
# ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc '/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq -e production'
# If you use the system's ruby:
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/restart.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is enabled using sudo systemctl enable reboot_site.service

However when I now reboot the server the script stops execution after the following line

```
sudo -u deployer -H bash -l
```

Server is an AWS EC2 AIM instance
What's wrong with my configuration to make this work and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It stops on `sudo -u deployer -H bash -l` because your script just changes user and will not continue until you logout as this user. So the remaining commands in your script are not executed.

I would suggest the following version which uses `runuser`:

```
#!/bin/bash
runuser -l deployer -c 'cd /var/www/html/cms/ && ./server -e staging start'
```

Comment: @PeterVandePut No problem. If it worked, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: It works on one server but on another server with same setup getting error runuser: may not be used by non-root users

Comment: @PeterVandePut Your second server has a different configuration, it can't be same, otherwise it would work. What exactly are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to run a script on startup you can configure a crontab for this

#crontab -e
@reboot  /home/ec2-user/restart.sh

Comment: This is the best answer to restart the rails server using bash script and crontab. Thanks a lot.